# Как вывести данные на API Яндекс Карт

Tags: yandex-maps-api, angular

Вопрос может показаться глупым, но что такое Angular я узнал 4 дня назад, а API Яндекс карт открыл для себя лишь сегодня

**Задача:**
Нужно отобразить пришедшие заявки с https://www.powernet.com.ru/connection на API Яндекс карт в проекте-болванке Angular ([github](https://github.com/VChuharev/test))

**Вопрос:** Не понимаю, с чего подступиться к данной теме. Готовый код не высылайте, пожалуйста, сам хочу разобраться, но прошу как-то направить, ибо перебираю все подряд в YouTube/Google

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите сначала сторонние модули для интеграции Яндекс Карт в Angular, которые упомянуты в документации: https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/#plugins

Быть может какой-нибудь из них вам подойдёт.